# How to close the SideBar menu manually when using SWRevealViewController ( ios)

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a `SideBar` / slide out menu using the `SWRevealViewController`. I have a  bunch of menus. One of the menu is to get app version info. So When I click on the cell, An `AlertView` displays the version number and on pressing the OK button I would like to close/hide the `SideBar` menu and return to the pervious view(front controller). For example, if I am on log in controller and I press the settings button to reveal the side bar and I choose version menu from `TableView` cells, a pop will open displaying version# and when I press Ok, the `SideBar` should close and return to the login screen without me having to tap the settings button again or swiping to return. How can I return to the login screen when I press OK on the alert view.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked OK
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

      //close the side bar and return to front view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I have menu **Exit** with alert YES / NO. When pressing NO I need to go back to the same menu. I remember last called `segue` (menu) and I call it again.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I just figured out the answer. I just use the following code to hide the side bar.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The correct answer is:

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
```

Comment: Firt yo must to check if your menu is open -> if (revealViewController().frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.right)

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is looking for a `swift` version, just use this single line:

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated()
```

Answer (score 2):

if the sidebar on left using:

```
    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
```

if was on the right using:

```
    self.revealViewController().rightRevealToggle(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Control it if it opened, if so close

```
if (self.revealViewController().frontViewPosition != FrontViewPosition.left) {
                    self.revealViewController?.revealToggle(animated: true)
                    
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

//View Did load add this
// Swift 4.2

```
func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
let leftMenuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: revealViewController, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftMenuItem, animated: true)

}
```